# Project Web App - related SharePoint site not provisioning?

Tags: project-server, ms-project

I am using Project Server 2016.  I have configured my PWA Connected SharePoint Sites setting to "Allow users to choose" to provision a connected SharePoint site when publishing a project.

When I go through the steps of saving a local .mpp file to the server, and then publishing the project, in the MS Project client, I get a dialog asking if I want to create a site.

I choose the option to yes, create a site, and I specify the URL.

After publishing is complete, no SharePoint site was created.

Why?

Comment: Could you check the queue jobs status? if failed with error please share with us the error code